# Unable to inherit from base.html.twig

Tags: symfony, twig

Below is my directory structure. Views folder has a sub-folder called `Default` which has `home.html.twig` template,this template is rendered by a method in `DefaultController`.
While `base.html.twig` is in `views` folder.

```
|--views
|----Default
|------home.html.twig
|----base.html.twig
```

**code for base.html.twig**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>testing</h1>    
    </body>
</html>
```

**code for home.html.twig**

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}
```

As `home.html.twig` extends `base.html.twig` so `home.html.twig` must show `<h1>testing</h1>` but its not being displayed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code for home.html.twig should be:

```
{% extends 'ProjectAppBundle::base.html.twig' %}
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html

Answer (score 2):

If your view is inside a bundle you must not use `{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}` because that base.html.twig is normally located in Symfony/app/resources/views/base.html.twig

Inside a bundle you should try something like `{% extends '@ProjectApp/base.html.twig' %}`

'Project' is the namespace and App is the bundle's name, so that base.html.twig would be located in Symfony/src/Project/AppBundle/Resources/views/

Hope that helps!